# How to set the QR code style generated by iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, qr-code

I use the following method to generate QR code：

```
    // 1. 
    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIQRCodeGenerator"];
    // 
    [filter setDefaults];
    
    // 2. 
    NSString *string = @"http://192.168.0.116/1";
    NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    // 
    [filter setValue:data forKeyPath:@"inputMessage"];
    
    // 3. 
    CIImage *image = [filter outputImage];
    
    // 4. 
    CGFloat scaleX = self.imageView.frame.size.width / image.extent.size.width;
    CGFloat scaleY = self.imageView.frame.size.height / image.extent.size.height;
    image = [image imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleX, 
    scaleY)];
    self.imageView.image  = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:image scale:[UIScreen 
    mainScreen].scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];`
```

Got this picture：
[image]

But what I want is this denser two-dimensional code image like this:
[image]

How do I style it thanks very much

Comment: But you have far less bytes to encode, so of course the result is less dense.

Comment: I just want to open a website. How can I make it dense

Comment: Add a dummy parameter to the address long enough until you get the density you want

Comment: Thank you very much for resolving my confusion